# would it be practical to use the Google App Engine webapp framework to send HTTP POST

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, xml-rpc

I need to do XML RPC and for the sake of simplicity and ease of use I was thinking the smallest WSGI framework would be the best choice so I looked at webapp.  The Google examples show their WSGI framework webapp being used to receive HTTP POST.  I need to receive POST but I also need to send POST.  Is use of webapp impractical in this case?  (I say impractical rather than impossible because perhaps nothing is impossible.)

The "cookbook" example for Google App Engine and XML RPC uses webapp but it also shows POST being received but not sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To *make* POST requests *from* AppEngine to another site, you want to use the urlfetch service of GAE:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/

Comment: This method seems to be independent of the choice of WSGI framework which is a little surprising.  Any insight into why this is being done outside of CherryPy or Django, etc?

Comment: "The URL Fetch service uses Google's network infrastructure for efficiency and scaling purposes."